# Bone Heat Weighting Failed (Automatic weight paint not working)

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting

I have an object that won't work with automatic weight paint. I have looked through multiple threads and tried multiple things with no solution. I have attached the .blend file if someone with experience can take a look. Here's a list of things I've tried:

- Made sure scale, location, rotation is applied
- Made sure the rig and mesh had the same origin
- Merged vertices by distance (I think this is equivalent to removing doubles?)
- Recalculated normals
- Attempted to scale x10 the mesh and rig and then tried automatic weight paint which resulted in Blender crashing :')

Thanks in advance for any help!

https://gofile.io/d/oK3DqD
**(I forgot to generate the rig before uploading the file)**

Comment: Can you add more info about your model and what does not work? A screenshot of the topology, has it loose parts, multiple objects? Do you get an error message? Is weight painting messed up? I appreciate that you shared your file but it's 500 MB to download.

Comment: Just to be sure: Do you try to rig the hi-poly demon girl?

Comment: Yes i did; should i attempt to decimate her? Will that help?

Comment: Decimating her solved it! thanks so much

Comment: Yes, over 2 million faces are too many to animate (and texture). You can use (and probably already did) the Decimate modifier with the "Un-Subdivide" option to reduce her face count down to 38k. The strings at the top of her boots can be separated. They are rather low-poly. If you want to animate her face I recommend to retopologize the mesh for a better edge flow (loops around the mouth and eyes). Or use a good, clean, low-poly base mesh and pull it in shape in the Sculpt mode.

Comment: Make sure your meshes aren't high poly. :)